# How to make one button visible when another is clicked in Flutter/Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I know how to make elements visible or invisible using the Visibility widget. Here is my code:

```
// New Game route
class NewGameRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  const NewGameRoute({key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'New Game',
      home: ListFromCSV1(),
    );
  }
}

class ListFromCSV1 extends StatefulWidget {
  const ListFromCSV1({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ListFromCSVState1 createState() => _ListFromCSVState1();
}

class _ListFromCSVState1 extends State<ListFromCSV1> {
  List<List<dynamic>> _listData = [
    [""]
  ];
  int _listCount = 0;
  bool _isFirstLoad = true;
  String assetPath = "files/main.jpg";

  @override
  void initState() {
    _loadCSV();
  }

  // This function is only triggered at init, so we only load csv once
  void _loadCSV() async {
    String rawData = await rootBundle.loadString("files/Text.csv");
    _listData = const CsvToListConverter().convert(rawData);
    assetPath = _listData[_listCount][1] == ""
        ? "files/main.jpg"
        : _listData[_listCount][1];
  }

  // This function is triggered when my button is pressed
  void _nextCSV() {
    setState(() {
      _listData = _listData;
      _listCount < _listData.length - 1
          ? _isFirstLoad
          ? _isFirstLoad = false
          : _listCount++
          : _listCount;
      assetPath =
      _listData[_listCount][1] == "" ? assetPath : _listData[_listCount][1];
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('New Game'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage(assetPath),
                fit: BoxFit.cover)),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            Visibility(
              child: Column(
              children: [
                ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
                  child: Stack(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Positioned.fill(
                        child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              image: DecorationImage(
                                  image: AssetImage('files/sheet.jpg'),
                                  fit: BoxFit.cover)),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(_listData[_listCount][0]),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                  children: [
                    ImageButton(label: 'OK', onButtonTap: _nextCSV),
                    ImageButton(label: 'Hide', onButtonTap: () {}),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
              visible: true,
            ),
            // your other widgets
            Visibility(
              child: ImageButton(label: 'Show', onButtonTap: () {}),
              visible: false,
            )

          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

//Class for a cool button
class ImageButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const ImageButton({Key? key, required this.label, required this.onButtonTap})
      : super(key: key);
  final String label;
  final Function onButtonTap;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () => onButtonTap(),
      child: Container(
        // customize you button shape and size and design
        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8, horizontal: 32),
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(2)),
            image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage("files/sheet.jpg"), // you can also pass the image dynamically with variable created for the widget.
                fit: BoxFit.cover)),
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            label,
            style: const TextStyle(
                color: Colors
                    .black, // you can get dominant colour on image and change the text color accordingly or apply shadows to the text
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                fontSize: 16),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The part with Visible/Invisible elements only:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('New Game'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage(assetPath),
                fit: BoxFit.cover)),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            Visibility(
              child: Column(
              children: [
                ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
                  child: Stack(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Positioned.fill(
                        child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              image: DecorationImage(
                                  image: AssetImage('files/sheet.jpg'),
                                  fit: BoxFit.cover)),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(_listData[_listCount][0]),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                  children: [
                    ImageButton(label: 'OK', onButtonTap: _nextCSV),
                    ImageButton(label: 'Hide', onButtonTap: () {}),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
              visible: true,
            ),
            // your other widgets
            Visibility(
              child: ImageButton(label: 'Show', onButtonTap: () {}),
              visible: false,
            )

          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

//Class for a cool button
class ImageButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const ImageButton({Key? key, required this.label, required this.onButtonTap})
      : super(key: key);
  final String label;
  final Function onButtonTap;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () => onButtonTap(),
      child: Container(
        // customize you button shape and size and design
        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8, horizontal: 32),
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(2)),
            image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage("files/sheet.jpg"), // you can also pass the image dynamically with variable created for the widget.
                fit: BoxFit.cover)),
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            label,
            style: const TextStyle(
                color: Colors
                    .black, // you can get dominant colour on image and change the text color accordingly or apply shadows to the text
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                fontSize: 16),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

But how to make a class to do the following:

1. First my screen looks like this:

[image]

2. When I click on the Hide button, it looks like this:

[image]

3. When I click on the Show button, it looks like this again:

[image]

That is, when these buttons are clicked, the visible values for the Column and ImageButton should change from true to false and vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provide you the whole code, check this out::

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    void main() {
      runApp(const MyApp());
    }
    
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          title: 'Flutter Demo',
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          ),
          home: const NewGameRoute(title: 'New Game'),
        );
      }
    }
    
    class NewGameRoute extends StatefulWidget {
      const NewGameRoute({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
    
      final String title;
    
      @override
      State<NewGameRoute> createState() => _NewGameRouteState();
    }
    
    class _NewGameRouteState extends State<NewGameRoute> {
      bool isPressed = false;
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text(widget.title),
          ),
          body: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  isPressed == false ? hideButton() : showButton(),
                ],
              )),
        );
      }
    
      Widget hideButton() {
        return Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('Text1 aaaa aaaaa aaaa aaaa',
                style: TextStyle(backgroundColor: Colors.grey)),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: Text(
                    'OK',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      isPressed = true;
                    });
                  },
                  child: Text(
                    'Hide',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            )
          ],
        );
      }
    
      Widget showButton() {
        return Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    isPressed = false;
                  });
                },
                child: Text(
                  'Show',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. This is a great Visibility widget alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with below code :

```
class NewGameRoute extends StatefulWidget {
  const NewGameRoute({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<NewGameRoute> createState() => _NewGameRouteState();
}

class _NewGameRouteState extends State<NewGameRoute> {
  bool isPressed = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              isPressed == false ? hideButton() : showButton(),
            ],
          )),
    );
  }

  Widget hideButton() {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Text('Text1 aaaa aaaaa aaaa aaaa',
            style: TextStyle(backgroundColor: Colors.grey)),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text(
                'OK',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  isPressed = true;
                });
              },
              child: Text(
                'Hide',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget showButton() {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                isPressed = false;
              });
            },
            child: Text(
              'Show',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I see this error when I try to implement your code: lib/main.dart:272:81: Error: Required named parameter 'title' must be provided.
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const NewGameRoute()),
                                                                                ^
lib/main.dart:912:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  const NewGameRoute({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: you just need to put title in a string, when you use NewGameRoute class.

Answer (score 0):

I found the simplest solution:

1. Add this before the widget creating the screen:

```dart
bool isVisible = true; // will be visible for the first frame
```

2. Add function for desired buttons:

```dart
ImageButton(label: 'Hide', onButtonTap: () {
    setState(() {
        isVisible = !isVisible;
    });
}),
```